Can I find the inverse of a polynomial directly in its NTT form?
I'm working with polynomials in the context of the Number Theoretic Transform (NTT), which is often used in cryptographic applications. I understand how to compute the inverse of a polynomial $f(x)$ in its coefficient representation, provided that it exists (i.e., $f(x)$ is invertible modulo $x^n−1$ and a prime modulus).
However, I'm curious if it's possible to directly compute the inverse of a polynomial when it is already in its NTT-transformed form. Specifically:

Is there an efficient algorithm to compute the inverse of a polynomial directly in its NTT form, or must I revert it to the coefficient domain first?
Are there any conditions or constraints on the polynomial or the modulus $q$ (e.g., q being prime) that would make this operation possible or impossible?

I would appreciate an explanation or references to relevant literature. Thank you!

If $\ g(x)\ $ is the inverse $\mod{x^n-1}\ $ of $\ f(x)\ $ over whatever field $\ F\ $ you're working in, and $\ \omega\ $ is a primitive $\ n^\text{th}\ $ root of unity (in the splitting field of $\ x^n-1\ $ over $\ F\ $), then you have
$$
g(x)f(x)=1+m(x)\big(x^n-1\big)\ .
$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
g\big(\omega^j\big)f\big(\omega^j)&=1+m\big(\omega^j)\big(\omega^{jn}-1\big)\\
&=1\ ,
\end{align}
and
$$
g\big(\omega^j)=f\big(\omega^j\big)^{-1}
$$
for $\ j=0,1,\dots n-1\ .$ You can therefore find $\ g(x)\ $ by using the Lagrange interpolation formula:
$$
g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f\big(\omega^i\big)^{-1}\prod_{j=0\\j\ne i}^{n-1}\left(\frac{x-\omega^j}{\omega^i-\omega^j}\right)\ .
$$
The only condition required for this to work is the same as that for $\ f(x)\ $ to be invertible $\mod{x^n-1}\ $—namely that $\ f(x)\ $ and $\ x^n-1\ $ be relatively prime, or, equivalently, that $\ f\big(\omega^j\big)\ne 0\ $ for $\ j=0,1,\dots n-1\ .$ I've no idea how the efficiency of this method compares with that of any other method of finding $\ g(x)\ ,$ though.

The Lagrange interpolation step won’t be too efficient, but your equation directly before this states that “the NTT of the inverse is the inverse of each coefficient of the NTT”, which is efficient. Converting back to $g$ from these NTT coefficients can be done using standard techniques (inverse NTT) efficiently.
